# Any suggestions to solve shielded jumpers between different PCBs?

Tags: pcb, cables, pcb-assembly, cable-assemblies

I've a problem where I got one PCB and then another and I need to get some small power, ground and signals from the other PCB to the other one.

The power and signals will also need shielding and good insulation.

Do anyone here happen to know any good cost effective, solution for this?
I have looked at flat shielded cables but been unable to find anything I like due to I have a hard time finding the connector housing fitting my needs.

---

What I'm looking for

I'm looking for a connector and cable with shielding, the connector in one end would must suitable not build height over <3mm or <3.5mm, if that isn't possible the lowest possible is still wanted.

The cable and connector need to withstand vibration over a long period of time >10-15 years, it's fine to glue it or mold it in around the connectors. It may also be okey to change the cable every 5 year if the connector can handle it.

The insulation on the cable to surrounding should be some 100Vdc, the insulation is mostly for functional however the higher the nicer (wished target 500Vdc, with no added insulation on top).

Ideal would be a 24 pin cable or depending on solution (haven't decided yet) a 9 pin cable could be sufficient, cables in parallel would also work if not taking to much place.

1 pair for power and ground return is needed in above, a 100mW carrying capacity at 3-5V should be more than sufficient.

Comment: What is it about the cables and connectors you already looked at that doesn't work for you? Without that information we're just going to suggest some common cable types, and you're going to keep telling us you already thought of that and it won't work for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

If both PCB are on the same plane, you can use small PCB to PCB connector, and design a small PCB which has the right shape to get to where you want.

You can do a 3 layers PCB with the outer layer being the shielding and have the traces in the inner layer.

Otherwise you might look at cable assemblies for laptop screen, usually they are shielded cable attached to the PCB.

Comment: Sadly the PCB:s will be placed on different levels.

Comment: How about to use HDMI cable ? HDMI socket are very cheap, and you can have small HDMI cable.

Comment: hmm, I wonder how good the interconnection would be during time and vibrations.
The device will have a life cycle off over 10 years or more.

Comment: I'm not aware of any pcb fab that will do three layer boards. They're always even numbers.

Comment: @Felthry, I've done 3 layers pcb a few times.